# Webdriver IO - Unable to find element with CSS selector with ID

Tags: webdriver-io

I am writing a simple WDIO selector with following statement. I was able to uniquely idenitfy it in browser. Not sure why WDIO was not able to set the value.

````
Given(/^I am on the login page$/, function () {
    browser.url('https://secure-sandbox.modulrfinance.com/')
    browser.maximizeWindow()
});

When(/^I enter password as \"([^\"]*)\"$/, function (password:string) {
    //const txt_username = $('#username-inp')
    //const txt_password = $('#password-inp')
    $('#username-inp').setValue('')
    $('#password-inp').setValue(password)
});

Then(/^I should see a flash message under username saying \"([^\"]*)\"$/, async function () {
    const banner = await $('#.ng-star-inserted')
    expect(banner).toHaveText('This field is required1')
});```

**error**
**[0-0]   error: 'no such element',
[0-0]   message: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#password-inp"}\n'** +
````

Comment: Can you add your DOM details for this element?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are testing `Single Page Application` written in `angular`. You have to deal with the asynchronous behavior of Angular, by adding appropriate waits(`Implicit`, `Explicit` or `Fluent` waits).

Check this [example](https://medium.com/slalom-build/testing-angular-applications-with-selenium-java-4bca1c6d08b5).